# Create a Scrollbar for a bitmap

Tags: c, winapi

I want to create a Scrollbar (horizontal and vertical) for a bitmap that will be drawn on my Window.

If the bitmap width is 300, should I set the horizontal Scrollbar range from 0 to 299, and this way if the user set the scroll box position to 40, I would just redraw the bitmap starting from the 41th pixel? (and the same goes for the vertical Scrollbar).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to scroll the window bitmap by yourself, you can use [the ScrollWindow function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787591(v=vs.85).aspx).
Enabling the horizontal and vertical bars adding `WS_HSCROLL` and `WS_VSCROLL` styles to window creation the scroll will be handled automatically by the system.

An example of how to use the function is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32925/Scrollable-Dialog-in-Pure-Win-API).

Comment: [ScrollWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787591.aspx): *"The **ScrollWindow** function is provided for backward compatibility. New applications should use the [**ScrollWindowEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787593.aspx) function."*